# Scrolling to specific part of another webpage onclick

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

So I have a custom image that links to contact page. On this page, when contact is clicked from the home page it scrolls to a specific div(Contact form).

I have been searching the web and stumble into a [scrollto](http://flesler.blogspot.ca/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) plugin from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652944/jquery-page-scroll-to-different-page) but it seems it only goes a different part of the same page (not certain but it didn't work for me).

Can anyone guide me to "Create a link that traverse to another page then scroll to a specific div" thank you. An example would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for the page to load, and then scroll down to the div of choice??

Comment: I want to create a special exemption onclick on a specific image that loads on a contact page then scrolls to specific div. So only when that link is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use *anchors* and then use `#` in the `href` to reference the name:

```
<a name="css-tutorials">CSS Tutorials</a>

<a href="#css-tutorials">Cascading Style Sheet Tutorials</a>
```

Examples were taken from [here](http://www.expression-web-tutorials.com/anchor-tags.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JSfiddle of a window scrolling to a div ID based on the URL. It could be modified to fire on a click event, or on a page load to read the URL for the ID being passed. Let me know if the example needs some adjusting.

This uses jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/jmKUw/1/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass the name of the div to scroll to, perhaps as a query string, to the contact page, and store it in a hidden input.

Then in a $(document).ready(function () {}); block, call your scrollto function, passing it the value of the hidden input.