# jQuery - Scroll to href on same page, and when going to different page

Tags: jquery

I have the below jQuery code, I want the scroll to animation to work when on the same page and when you click on another page.

At the moment I have the following:-

```
jQuery('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    var jtarget = jQuery(target);

    jQuery('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': jtarget.offset().top
    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
```

It is going to the section but no animation is happening.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: you mean swing animation not run?

Comment: That's correct @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: for this animation you need to include jquery-ui  It will not work with just jquery .. try to include jquery-ui and try again and let me know if it works

Comment: added https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js but the animation still doesn't seem to be happening

Comment: I will try to make a demo please wait

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery page scroll to different page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652944/jquery-page-scroll-to-different-page)

Comment: Ok nsliva .. as I tested .. this effects working at least with jquery 1.9.1 with jquery-ui .. to know about effects you can take a look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_easings.htm .. and see this demo as well https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/vzexkLxq/ .. if you downgrade the jquery version in my demo the effect will not work as expected