# HTML how to go back a page and scroll to a specific point in the page

Tags: javascript, html

In my website I have a contact section on the home page. When you click the contact link in the navigation bar it scrolls down to the contact section. I have done this by using `#contact` which is the name of the div of the contact section.

My question is how do I link to this from different pages so when contact is clicked on another page it directs to the homepage and then scrolls down to the div section.

I have linked a codepen below to explain the situation better.

https://codepen.io/CODEN000B/project/editor/XpyyGp

Answer (score 1):

Anchor the page you want to go to.

`<a href="/my/path/index.html#contact">link to contact</a>`

Answer (score 1):

To add a anchor hyperlink (section) to the page do the following within anotherpage.html

```
<a name="sectiontoscrollto"></a>
```

Then link or it from the other page like this

```
<a href="anotherpage.html#sectiontoscrollto">Another Page</a>
```

Comment: This did not work for me for some reason, it just says "Your file was not found
It may have been moved or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Comment: Check that the link address points to the correct file name and that the file exists

Answer (score 0):

this is duplicated question , but i will work an example for you soon and paste on comment section for your code in codepen.io 
i will not use the same way on the duplicated post  , as it may help others 
here is a link which answered your question .

[jQuery scroll to ID from different page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652944/jquery-scroll-to-id-from-different-page)

[click here to download](https://files.fm/u/689p4wma) your files which you upload in codepen.io with the scrolling from another page

here as well the code you should place on index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<!-- navigation bar -->
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>


<div class="nav">
    <div class="nav-header">
        <div class="nav-title">



        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-btn">
        <label for="nav-check">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-check">
    <div class="nav-links">

        <a href="index.html" onclick="myFunction()">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="anotherpage.html"  onclick="myFunction()">Another Page</a>


    </div>
</div>
<!-- navigation bar ends -->
<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
var scrolflag = localStorage.getItem("storageName")
if (scrolflag = "scrolltocontact") { 
console.log( "ready!" );
var elmnt = document.getElementById("contactus");
elmnt.scrollIntoView();

localStorage.setItem("normal")
alert(scrolflag);

}

});

</script>

<div id="firstsection">

When you click "Contact Us" in the navigation bar it automaticially scrolls 
down to the contact us section. I have done this by using #contactus as a 
link 
which is also the name of the div. However when I go to another page I would 
still like this to work in the navigation bar. Please click Another Page to 
continue.<br><br>

Added text to show scrolling.<br><br>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in 


</div>

<div style="height:5in;"> 
lorium lourm <br>
lorium lourm <br>
lorium lourm <br>
lorium lourm <br>
lorium lourm <br>
<div>

<div id="contactus">
<h1>Contact Us</h1>
    <p>If you would like to contact us for any reason, drop us a message 
below, add an email address if you would like a reply.</p>
    <p> Name: <br> <input type="text" id="firstname"name=""></p>
    <p> Email: <br> <input type="text" id="email" name=""></p>
    <p> Message:  <br><textarea id="message"rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

```
</div>
```

and this code for Anotherpage.html :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<!-- navigation bar -->
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
```

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="nav-header">
        <div class="nav-title">



        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-btn">
        <label for="nav-check">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="nav-check">
    <div class="nav-links">

        <a href="index.html" onclick="myFunction()">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="anotherpage.html"  onclick="myFunction()">Another Page</a>

    </div>
</div>
<script>
window.onload = function() {

}
</script>


<!-- navigation bar ends -->
<script>

function myFunction() {


 var getInput = "scrolltocontact"
localStorage.setItem("storageName",getInput);
 location.replace("index.html")
}
</script>

</script>
<div id="firstsection">

How do I make it so when I click contact us it puts me back on my home page 
(index.html) and then scrolls down to contact us section. Thanks for your 
help.


</div>
```

the style.css will remain the same ,

let me know if you need any further help , i have created a local variable to indicate the clicking of contact us and i am calling that variable from anotherpage.html to index.html and with if condition i am scrolling based on that set value . you will have to clear storage after scrolling or it will keep scrolling  .. i left it this way so you can have an idea how to do it ...
good luck & let me know if you need any further help .

Comment: hello m here is a link you may download your files i took them from codepen.io and i applied what you need in it ,

Comment: We don't answer dupe's, we vote/flag to close them as duplicate.

Comment: sorry!! i thought i already edited my post , i did the same function but in different method unlike the one been used on the duplicated post, this could be useful for others too ...

Comment: Nope, external code samples, or downloadable files, is of no use to other users, as when that link dies, so does this answer. Follow SO's policies and post code samples _within_ the answer and you likely will avoid downvotes.

Comment: on this case i can edit my post and add that code ?

Comment: @Yes...and let me know when done and I'll review and reconsider my down vote

Comment: thanks for your valid point , it make sense to post the code and you are right , external links may get down  , i have added my code :)